# How calculate pearson correlation between two pandas timeline vectors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timeline

I have a database of users posts in a social network, Using Pandas DataFrame I counted the monthly number of posts of each user, which resulted in a 2 column table for each user containing the month and number of posts. I want to  calculate the monthly count correlation between different users, knowing that the monthly timelines are differents between each two users ( with some intersected months)

This is the code for creating a monthly timeline table (agg)

```
# Create an empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
# Create a column from the datetime variable
df['datetime'] = date_list
# Convert that column into a datetime datatype
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Set the datetime column as the index
df['score'] = count
df.index = df['datetime'] 
# this is the table containing posts count for each month
agg = df['score'].resample('M').sum().to_frame()
```

So basically I have to apply a correlation function on two "agg" variables, but couldn't find an intuitive way to do it. 
Here is two examples of agg variable belonging to two different users:

First column : `Month` ,Second column : `Number of posts`.

```
User A 
2018-04-30     39
2018-05-31     41
2018-06-30     19
2018-07-31     46
2018-08-31     61
2018-09-30     57
2018-10-31     33
2018-11-30     18

User B:
2017-11-30      0
2017-12-31      3
2018-01-31      0
2018-02-28      0
2018-03-31      22
2018-04-30      3
2018-05-31      11
```

Comment: please use the formatting provided for writing the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution to calculus the pearson correlation:

```
import pandas as pd
data = """    
datetime     score 
2018-04-30     39
2018-05-31     41
2018-06-30     19
2018-07-31     46
2018-08-31     61
2018-09-30     57
2018-10-31     33
2018-11-30     18
    """
    datb = """    
datetime      score 
2017-11-30      0
2017-12-31      3
2018-01-31      0
2018-02-28      0
2018-03-31      22
2018-04-30      3
2018-05-31      11
        """
dfa = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
dfb = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(datb), sep='\s+')
dfa['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa['datetime'])
dfb['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(dfb['datetime'])
dfa.index = dfa['datetime']
dfb.index = dfb['datetime']

agga = dfa['score'].resample('M').sum().to_frame()
aggb = dfb['score'].resample('M').sum().to_frame()
print(agga,aggb)
```

---

```
#intersection of 2 dataframes on datetime
inter = agga.merge(aggb, on='datetime')
print(inter)
result = inter['score_x'].corr(inter['score_y'])
print(result)
```

---

```
 dfa
           score
datetime         
2018-04-30     39
2018-05-31     41
2018-06-30     19
2018-07-31     46
2018-08-31     61
2018-09-30     57
2018-10-31     33
2018-11-30     18

 dfb
             score
datetime         
2017-11-30      0
2017-12-31      3
2018-01-31      0
2018-02-28      0
2018-03-31     22
2018-04-30      3
2018-05-31     11

 inter
            score_x  score_y
datetime                    
2018-04-30       39        3
2018-05-31       41       11

 result
0.9999999999999999
```

If you want to use union:

```
union = pd.merge(agga, aggb, on='datetime', how='outer').fillna(0)
```

output of union:

```
                score_x  score_y
datetime                    
2018-04-30     39.0      3.0
2018-05-31     41.0     11.0
2018-06-30     19.0      0.0
2018-07-31     46.0      0.0
2018-08-31     61.0      0.0
2018-09-30     57.0      0.0
2018-10-31     33.0      0.0
2018-11-30     18.0      0.0
2017-11-30      0.0      0.0
2017-12-31      0.0      3.0
2018-01-31      0.0      0.0
2018-02-28      0.0      0.0
2018-03-31      0.0     22.0
```

a good link to understant [merge](https://data36.com/pandas-tutorial-3-important-data-formatting-methods-merge-sort-reset_index-fillna/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do we apply apply pearson correlation only on intersected months? shoudn't we do the union of the two timelines ?

Comment: for correlation, you have to compare same "sort" of elements, i have done intersection for that . if you do union you'll have NaN value because some months  have no values.. so after you'll have to estimate the missing values (sorry for my english)

Comment: Is there a way for expanding the two timelines by filling  0 score in the non existing months  instead of NaN ? so that I can apply easly the pearson on the union timelines?

Comment: by the way, votre anglais est parfait ;)

Comment: please dont forget to validate the answer if is okay. thanks